# How can i update table when counter reach a specific value? (thread safe)

Tags: mysql

I increase a field when somebody click the image. Also i want to update (decrease) customer budget when counter value reach to 1k. It is like that:

```
UPDATE click SET count = count + 1 WHERE customer_id = 1;
UPDATE budget JOIN click ON budget.customer_id = click.customer_id
 SET budget.total_budget = budget.total_budget - 10, click.count = 0
 WHERE budget.customer_id = 1 AND click.count = 1000;
```

But it should be thread safe, i don't want to decrease budget 2 times when 2 clicks happen same time. My question is how can do this with mysql?

Answer (score 0):

Add a [trigger](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/trigger-syntax.html) that updates `budget` when `count` exceeds a certain value.